# Mathematical function for a gradually falling parabolic curve in 1st quadrant

Tags: conic-sections, interpolation

I need a mathematical function for $y=f(x)$ such that $f(0)=25$ and decreases gradually to $f(100)=0$. Ideally, the function should look something like below, decreasing gradually for lower values of $x(<30)$ but faster for higher values of $x$.
Approximate plot values:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
x&0&5&10&20&30&50&60&70&90&100\\\hline
y&25&24&22&18&15&10&8&5&2&0
\end{array}
$$

Edit : For my requirements I believe an inverted parabolic function would be a better fit than for a choice of negative exponent ( with $y$ sign reversed)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more precise. You said that you want it to "decrease exponentially". Do you mean that the function should be of the form $y(x)= A e^{kx}$, with $A$ and $k$ constants?

Comment: Do you need the function to go through exactly these points? If so, the quickest way is to fit a polynomial to the data set.

Comment: yes, I need the function to go through these points exactly

Comment: I am okay even if the function is not an exponential function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following code in MATLAB,

```
x = [0 5 10 20 30 50 60 70 90 100];
y = [25 24 22 18 15 10 8 5 2 0];
f = fit(x', y', 'exp1')
```

you can find an expression of the form $a\cdot\exp(b\cdot x)$ that fits best through your given points. The above code snippet results in

```
General model Exp1:
ans(x) = a*exp(b*x)
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a =       26.62  (24.19, 29.04)
   b =    -0.02188  (-0.02615, -0.01761)
```

The plot below shows the curve.

```
plot(f, x, y)
```

[image]

---

Extending upon this, you can also find an expression as a sum of two exponentials of the form $a\cdot\exp(b\cdot x) + c\cdot\exp(d\cdot x)$ by replacing

```
f = fit(x', y', 'exp1')
```

with

```
f = fit(x', y', 'exp2')
```

The result is

```
General model Exp2:
f(x) = a*exp(b*x) + c*exp(d*x)
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a =      -7.941  (-79.16, 63.28)
   b =    0.003243  (-0.04323, 0.04971)
   c =       33.37  (-37.4, 104.1)
   d =    -0.01101  (-0.03311, 0.01108)
```

and
[image]
This plot fits through most of your points.

---

According to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html), you can use the following commands to find polynomial functions:

1. Of form $p_1\cdot x^2 + p_2\cdot x + p_3$ with

`f = fit(x', y', 'poly2')`

which results in

```
Linear model Poly2:
f(x) = p1*x^2 + p2*x + p3
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p1 =    0.001145  (0.0007975, 0.001492)
   p2 =      -0.365  (-0.3998, -0.3302)
   p3 =       25.28  (24.63, 25.93)
```

and
[image]

2. Of form $p_1\cdot x^3 + p_2\cdot x^2 + p_3\cdot x + p_4$ with

`f = fit(x', y', 'poly3')`

which results in

```
Linear model Poly3:
f(x) = p1*x^3 + p2*x^2 + p3*x + p4
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p1 =  -4.791e-06  (-1.961e-05, 1.003e-05)
   p2 =    0.001867  (-0.0003975, 0.004131)
   p3 =     -0.3922  (-0.484, -0.3004)
   p4 =       25.43  (24.6, 26.27)
```

and
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot that helps, do you think a parabolic function could better fit my requirements ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add fits for polynomials. Notice that with the points that you have mentioned in the original post, the polynomials are almost identical. You might want to try different points if you need a different shape of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions $$y_1=\frac{25}{e^{100}-1}(e^{100-x}-1) \qquad\text{and } y_2=\frac{25}{e^4-1}(e^{4-x/25}-1)$$ pass through $(0,25)$ and $(100,0)$, but it's unlikely they would pass near those inner points ($y_1$ is almost flat for $x>5$) since the inner points look somewhat linear (and are also integers). If the inner points matter so much, a fit (as suggested by others) will do.

**Last edit:** OP already choose an answer; I just wanted to give a last function before leaving the issue for good: $$y_3= \frac{25}{e-1}(e^{1-x/100}-1).$$

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't fit my plot points, it remains largely flat for x=[0,95]

Comment: Oh, sorry. I screwed up something.

Comment: Edit: $$y=\frac{25}{e^4-1}(e^{4-x/25}-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

One "almost exponential" function that's not a bad approximation of the function, would be
$$
y(x) = 42 e^{-0.0091x}-17
$$

On the other hand, if you want a polynomial that exactly fits the set of points, you need to solve for the coefficients $a_i$ of
$$
y(x) = \sum_{i=0}^9 a_i x^i
$$
With Python, I made the following code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

x = np.array([00.0, 05.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 90.0, 100.0])
y = np.array([25.0, 24.0, 22.0, 18.0, 15.0, 10.0, 08.0, 05.0, 02.0, 000.0])
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 9)

print z
```

and the result is

```
[ -2.35822733e-14   8.59716765e-12  -1.23964321e-09   8.81258004e-08  -2.96675445e-06   1.86358094e-05   1.67292491e-03  -4.42724486e-02  -2.11928208e-02   2.50000000e+01]
```

Mathematically put, the polynomial that you want is
$$
y(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \dots + a_9 x^9
$$
where
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccr}
a_9 &\approx& -2.35822733\times 10^{-14} \\
a_8 &\approx& 8.59716765\times 10^{-12} \\
a_7 & \approx& -1.23964321\times 10^{-09} \\
a_6 &\approx& 8.81258004\times 10^{-08} \\
a_5 & \approx& -2.96675445\times 10^{-7} \\
a_4 & \approx& 1.86358094\times 10^{-05} \\
a_3 & \approx& 1.67292491\times 10^{-03} \\
a_2 & \approx& -4.42724486\times 10^{-02} \\
a_1 & \approx& -2.11928208\times 10^{-02} \\
a_0  &=& 25 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This is a complicated expression but it should match the points exactly.